# Why don't I have a positive question record?

Tags: discussion, questions, badges

I am working towards the 'curious' badge (on the Arqade site), and one of the requirements is to *maintain a positive question record*.

As visible [on my profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/156661/the-pickle-tickler?tab=questions), I have asked 10 questions, of which all are positive except for one. Does *maintaining a positive question record* mean that *all* your questions must be positive, or just the majority? As it is now, the vast majority of my questions are positive, yet the badge tracker states that I still *need a positive question record*.

What am  I missing?

Comment: Deleted questions still count.

Comment: One is closed as a duplicate, and you might have some deleted ones. Closed and deleted questions affect your question record. See [Give users a way to see their “Positive Question Record” score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234963/299342)

Comment: @Null With `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`, Do questions double count? If a question is deleted and it is negative, does it count for both of the categories in this equation?

Comment: Yes, and potentially triple -- a closed, negative, and deleted question would count against your record three times.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I've mistyped a meta site when migrating...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you've asked questions that weren't... Positive. Most of these are deleted, of which you can still see the recent ones [on your profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/156661):

[image: three downvoted, deleted questions]

*All* questions count when determining your record.

Comment: What's a "positive question"

Comment: A question with a positive score.